# lxc-clone: unrecognized option '--dir'

Tags: ubuntu, lxc

I try to change rootfs dir while cloning like:

```
lxc-clone -o foo -n bar --dir /lxc/bar
```

but i got this error:

```
lxc-clone: unrecognized option '--dir'
```

Then i try to use "-B" option and "lvm" value to set rootfs in a LV:

```
lxc-clone -o foo -n bar -B lvm --vgname lxc-vg
```

and i get this error:

```
Error: vgname not supported
Usage: lxc-clone [-s] [-B backingstore] [-L size[unit]] [-K] [-M] [-H]
          [-p lxcpath] [-P newlxcpath] orig new

  -s: snapshot rather than copy
  -B: use specified new backingstore.  Default is the same as
      the original.  Options include aufs, btrfs, lvm, overlayfs, 
      dir and loop
  -L: for blockdev-backed backingstore, use specified size * specified
      unit. Default size is the size of the source blockdev, default
      unit is MB
  -K: Keep name - do not change the container name
  -M: Keep macaddr - do not choose a random new mac address
  -p: use container orig from custom lxcpath
  -P: create container new in custom lxcpath
```

Why i cant use "--vgname" or "--dir" with "lxc-clone"?
What am i doing wrong?
Is it possible to change rootfs dir while cloning a container?

PS: i use Ubuntu 14.04 and lxc 1.0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long time ago I thought it's a bug so reported in "launchpad". They answer me now, and I found out that I made a big mistake.

here the answer from launchpad:

> Hi,
>
> "dir" is just an option of -b/--backingstore not an option itself.
>
> So it has to be:
>
> ```
> sudo lxc-clone -o u1 -n u1-clone2 -B dir
> ```
>
> or:
>
> ```
> sudo lxc-clone -o u1 -n u1-clone4 --backingstore dir
> ```

and here the link to the page:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/lxc/+bug/1383245

hope to be useful